# Full Width Navigation Menu with sub menus

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm creating a navigation menu that has a black background the full width of the window. To do this, I've put the `ul` element inside a `div` that has `overflow: hidden;` set. However, because of this when the submenus are hovered they push around the top level `li` elements. The third level menus are also causing the second level `li` elements to expand in height to contain them. I'm also setting a negative margin on the `ul ul` elements to realign them. With `ul ul` using `position:absolute` they display normally but do not appear past the containing div, so I have `ul ul` set to `position:relative`. These are just the issues that I am aware of. How would I go about accomplishing a navigation menu with a full width background? I also want to make sure this works when there is multiple lines of `li` elements. Thanks.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BVvc6/170/

HTML

```
<div id="navigation"><div class="maxwidth">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Main</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
</div></div>
```

CSS

```
#header {height:70px; background:lightblue;}
.maxwidth { max-width: 1280px; width:90%; margin: 0 auto; }

#navigation {
    background:rgb(42,42,42);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 30px -10px black; 
    width: 100%;
    /* requires content to stay in div for full width background */
    overflow:hidden;
}

#navigation ul {
    margin:0; padding:0; 
    position: relative; 
}

#navigation a /* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
{
    color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; padding: 0 0 0 0px;

    /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#navigation li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

#navigation ul > li:hover { background: gray; }

#navigation ul ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    margin: 0px -20px;
    display: none;
}

#navigation ul ul li { display: block; width: 180px; right: -180px; background: rgb(42,42,42); }

#navigation li:hover > ul {
    display: inline;
}

#navigation ul ul ul {position: relative; left: 158px; }
```

Comment: How does this look? http://jsfiddle.net/BVvc6/173/

Comment: @BuddhistBeast Thanks! That's an improvement. I've fixed somethings and documented other issues: http://jsfiddle.net/BVvc6/175/

Comment: @michaellindal I'll work on it a bit more and get back to you soon :)

Comment: I've fixed all of your problems: http://jsfiddle.net/BVvc6/180/

Comment: If the above works for you, please let me know so I can throw it into an answer!

Comment: Thanks. Again, better, but not what I want. (Haven't had time to work on it, will disable `ul ul` until I have time to devote more time to that part of the site.) I'm sorry, I'm really picky. I don't want to have fixed widths, esp on the first level `li`s. Might start my CSS over from scratch. Also the black isn't full width anymore.

Comment: I understand.. I would consider rewriting that entire CSS code, this submenu process is kind of like inception haha. If you want, I can post an answer with many resources to create your drop down menu system.. or give you something better to work with?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44179/discussion-between-michaellindahl-and-buddhistbeast)

Comment: @BuddhistBeast I've answered this question with an almost complete solution, but there is one bug. If you wanted to check it out that would be great!

Comment: @BuddhistBeast After second look I got it to work. When I have time, I'm going to compare the two and see what I had to do to fix it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad you've found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

After a while of fiddling around and rewriting the css, I've managed to accomplish what I wanted to do. The issue has been updated on jsfiddle.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BVvc6/194/

CSS:

```
#navigation, #footer, #header {padding:0px 0px;text-shadows: 1px 1px 3px #000;}

#navigation {
    background:#2A2A2A;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px 0px black;
}

#navigation ul ul {
    background:#2A2A2A;
    border: black 1px solid;
}

#navigation ul ul li { border-bottom: black 1px solid; }
#navigation ul ul li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }


#navigation a
/* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
 {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
    display:block;
    padding: .6em;
}

#navigation ul {list-style: none; overflow:hidden; padding:0; margin:0;}

#navigation > .maxwidth > ul > li { float: left; padding: 0 .6em; }
#navigation > .maxwidth > ul > li > ul { margin-left: -.6em; } 

#navigation ul li:hover, #navigation ul li.hover { background: black; }

#navigation ul ul {display:none; position: absolute; overflow:visible;}
#navigation ul li {height: /*38px;*/ }

#navigation ul li:hover > ul, #navigation ul li.hover > ul { display: block; background: #2A2A2A;}

#navigation ul ul li { display: block; overflow:hidden; width: 12em; }

#navigation ul ul ul { left: 12em; margin-top:-2.4em; }
```